# change wow js animation starting point

Tags: html, css, wow.js

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/012x13sw/17/)

I have used wow js for animating few sections in my website. It worked perfectly. But I found that the animation is coming from the edge of the website. It took long way to come to the middle. So it's not looking nice. How can I adjust animation start point around this black line.

[image]

I played with wowjs default options. But no luck.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
```

Any solution?

Comment: as you can see in the CSS the fadein use translate3D(-100%,0,0) so -100% of the width of the element, so think about how you can use this information

Comment: How about the [scrollContainer parameter](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW#advanced-usage)?

Comment: @BillyNate No luck :(

Comment: @TemaniAfif It worked man! Thanks a lot!